# Windows 7 with two network connections needs to access specific host by name on specific connection

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I'm trying to reach the web server on a host on my local subnet that has an IP address on each of two network connections. When I am using only my local office connection, my request (using the host name) reaches the target just fine. Keep in mind, this particular host is also the local office DNS. However, when in addition I establish connection to the corporate intranet (using Junos Pulse SSL VPN), so now I have two network connections active, a request to the host by name goes to the corporate DNS, which apparently knows the name of my local host by a different, external IP that is unreachable. So when the corporate VPN is active, I cannot access web services from this target local host using its host name. I can still get to it using its local office IP address. Also note I have no problem accessing any other local server by its (local/unqualified) host name.

What I want, I think, is to learn how to jigger my Windows network configuration to make sure that the local DNS gets first crack at everything, and the corporate DNS comes after. I've already played with inserting the local IP of the local DNS, and also setting the local network connection metric to "1", but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to move the LAN connection ahead of the Junos VPN connection from Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections. Hit the Alt key to get the menu bar, select Advanced->Advanced Settings, another dialog pops up. In the Adaptors and Bindings tab, in the Connections pane, I selected the relevant Local Area Connection and clicked on the up-arrow button at the right of the pane to move this connection to the top.

I also set the Metric to 1 for this connection. This can be done starting from the Properties dialog on the Connection, selecting Internet Protocol version 4 and clicking on Properties, then in the dialog that opens clicking on Advanced, in the dialog that opens uncheck Automatic Metric and enter 1 in the text field. In the DNS tab of this dialog I made sure my local domain was at the top of the list in the pane under "Append these DNS suffixes (in order)".  OK your way back out of all open dialogs.